# Angular 13 live-reload not working, can websocket endpoint be configured?

Tags: angular, websocket, proxy

It seems like the path Angular uses for the its websocket in the dev build has changed.

Angular 12 & earlier: `ws://localhost:4200/websocket`

Angular 13: `ws://localhost:4200/ws`

This causes our app a problem because we use `/ws` for a websocket connection with our backend. We connect to our backend via a proxy, so the connection with both our server and Angular is `ws://localhost:4200/ws`. The path gets proxied, so Angular live-reload does not work.

Can the Angular websocket endpoint be configured?

Comment: I have done live reload with Nginx using a variation of this post: https://nathanfriend.io/2018/05/14/live-reloading-an-angular-2-app-behind-nginx.html. It seems like it is listening on `location ^~ /sockjs-node/`. Maybe it can help you. It worked on Angular 10, 11, 12 but I have not tried it on 13 yet.

Comment: Stopped working in angular 13.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a fix has already been merged into the angular-cli: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/23266. Could you try to update angular-cli to the latest 14 version or version 15. Both seem to have this issue fixed:

[14.2.x](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/14.2.x/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs/dev-server.ts#L307)
[15.0.x](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/15.0.x/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs/dev-server.ts#L307)

Comment: For my specific project I cannot upgrade to angular 14+. Its a big project with multiple teams needing to do the upgrade which would take a few months to get everyone on the same page.
Any thoughts on a fix for v13 ?

Comment: Can't you change the your app websocket path from `/ws` to something else, then there will not be any conflict with the live-reload websocket path. Will that not work?

Comment: Maybe @AmitVishwakarma but for my project its pretty confusing on how to change the path with the way its setup. It's a good point though. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @AlanRichards it might be possible to change the webpack configuration of angular-cli. If that is possible, you'd need to change the [DevServer configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwebsocketserver) of the webpack config. Take a look at [angular-builders](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders). That might help you further!

Comment: @Brent Ill look into Angular-Builders. Thanks for that!
I have been messing with the DevServer config for a few days now and can't seem to get anything to work. Part of the problem is that I get no real errors to tell me if I am close or far away from the solution so the best I can do is just try everything the docs state and hope it works. Fingers crossed the Angular-Builders stuff yields success.